# Reusing pictures in gallery from other posts

Tags: plugin-recommendation, gallery

I have two pages where I want to use galleries with the same pictures (those pages are in different languages). Is there any way to create a gallery with already uploaded images in the other post. By default it's not possible. maybe there is a plugin for this purpose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the default Gallery Shortcode within your post by specifying a post ID.

```
[gallery id="123"]
```

ID == the original post the photos to which the photos are attached.

Hope this helps.